# Cannot specify the operands when using inline asm outside a function

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

My code is

```c
unsigned long user_stack_pointer;

__asm__(
    ".global exception_handling_entry\n"
    "exception_handling_entry:\n"
    "add %0, sp, x0\n"
    : "=r" (user_stack_pointer)
);
```

gcc shows a error `')' before ':' token` when using `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc test.c -o test`. But it works well when I put the inline asm into a function such as

```c
unsigned long user_stack_pointer;

int main() {
    __asm__(
    ".global exception_handling_entry\n"
    "exception_handling_entry:\n"
    "addi %0, sp, 0\n"
    : "=r" (user_stack_pointer)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

This confuses me a lot.

I can not find a good solution for it.

Comment: You cannot use extended inline assembly outside of functions, it's not supported.  Use regular inline assembly or ideally write assembly code in an assembly source file.

Comment: Note also that for this use case, it's better to use a naked function instead of manually placing a label.  As is, your code is not guaranteed to end up in the text section and may not end up being executable.

Comment: @fuz Does gcc support naked function?

Comment: Thanks, gcc supports naked function on RISCV.

Comment: Note that gcc also supports `__builtin_stack_address` so no need for assembly at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At global scope, the code only runs if something jumps inside the asm statement itself.  There's no way for the path of execution in C terms to enter and leave the `asm` statement, so there's nowhere for the compiler to put code that sets up input operands or that stores output operands to associated C variables.  If you want that to happen, **you have to write code for it yourself, exactly like writing a function in a separate `.s` file.**  (Use `.text` inside your global-scope asm statement in case the compiler left the current section something else.)

e.g. `sd sp, user_stack_pointer` as a pseudo-instruction, or `auipc` with the `%hi` part of the address and use `%lo(user_stack_pointer)` as the offset in a store instruction.  Look at compiler-generated asm to see how it accesses global vars (https://godbolt.org/); I'm just going from memory and that might not be quite right for RV64; I might be remembering MIPS.

Or if you want to have the compiler do the `.global` and label for you, use `__attribute__((naked))`.  You still have to write the entire function body with Basic `asm` statements (no operands); **it's not officially supported to use Extended `asm` (with operands) in naked functions**: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Function-Attributes.html - but it's only at most a warning not a compile-time error, so the compiler won't stop you from relying on happens-to-work code.

Also, the compiler doesn't emit a `ret` at the end of a `naked` function, so can't let execution come out the bottom of your asm statement anyway, making an output operand useless.  You need to `ret` or jump somewhere.

---

It would actually be undefined behaviour if execution came out the bottom of the asm statement after jumping into the middle (e.g. like this exception handler rather than execution starting with the C `__asm__` statement itself) no matter where it is, even inside a function.  As [the GCC manual documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), *asm statements may not perform jumps into other asm statements, only to the listed GotoLabels. GCC’s optimizers do not know about other jumps; therefore they cannot take account of them when deciding how to optimize.*

If that happens to work, you got lucky.  The code for the `"=r"(global_var)` operand could rely on some registers set up by instructions the compiler put ahead of the `asm` statement, which wouldn't have executed if you jump into the middle of it.